# Do animal ghouls generally exist or are wolf ghouls an exception?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Until I looked up ghouls in the SRD I always thought there are ONLY humanoid ghouls then I saw a wolf ghoul which seemingly is an official pathfinder thing (from the magazines).

So I wonder there: Are there official templates for animal ghouls or are these an exception (and how can they exist then? ) and also how would animal ghouls react to normal ghouls and vice versa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## *Pathfinder* Says Nonhumanoid Ghouls Aren't Often a Thing

According to the [ghoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul)'s supernatural ability disease

> A *humanoid* who dies of ghoul fever rises as a ghoul at the next midnight. A humanoid who becomes a ghoul in this way retains none of the abilities it possessed in life. It is not under the control of any other ghouls, but it hungers for the flesh of the living and behaves like a normal ghoul in all respects. A *humanoid* of 4 Hit Dice or more rises as a ghast.

Emphasis mine. A creature whose type isn't [humanoid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids) who dies of ghoul fever *doesn't* become a ghoul.<sup>1</sup>

#### Exceptions

- [Ghoul bats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/skaveling) are [mobats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/bat-mobat)--magical beasts--that became ghouls after being "specially raised on diets of fungus and humanoid flesh. Upon reaching maturity, [urdefhans](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/Urdefhan) ritually slay the bats using necrotic poisons, then raise the corpses to serve as mounts and guardians."
- [Dire corbies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/corby-dire)--monstrous humanoids--"who feed solely on carrion have been known to succumb to ghoul fever and be reborn as undead ghoul corbies with a hunger for living flesh."

#### "What About the [Wolf Ghoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-wolf-TOHC)?"

The wolf ghoul is a third-party creature from Frog God Games' [*Tome of Horrors Complete*](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/collections/frog-god-games/products/pf-the-tome-of-horrors-complete) and is a ghoul in name only. Although possessing the ghoul's trademark paralytic attack, it doesn't spread ghoul fever.

More third party resources for ghouls are available [here](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/products/monster-focus-ghouls), [here](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/products/advanced-races-2-darakhul-ghouls), and [here](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/products/studies-of-decay-ghouls).

The [ghoul dire wolf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul/ghoul-wolf-dire)--apparently a foe in [*Ashes at Dawn*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8lv2?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-47-Ashes-at-Dawn), part 6 of the [Carrion Crown adventure path](http://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=carrion%20crown&includeUnrated=true&what=products&f=brand%2FPathfinder%20Adventure%20Path&includeUnavailable=true&sort=0)--appears to have been concocted so the PCs face creatures that have something to do with Urgathoa, the goddess of, among other things, gluttony and undead. The ghoul dire wolf, too, possesses the ghoul's paralytic attack but doesn't spread ghoul fever.

However, the template [dread ghoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dread-ghoul-cr-1) in the [*Advanced Bestiary*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932442162) [(the *Kickstarter* campaign for the *Pathfinder* version was funded on Dec. 9, 2013)](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1780208966/advanced-bestiary-for-the-pathfinder-rpg/posts?page=3) can be added to *any* living creature, permitting the DM a wide variety of wacky ghouls.

How dread ghoul animals and ghoul humanoids interact is the DM's call.

---

1. A humanoid *killed* by a [marrowstone golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-marrowstone) becomes a ghoul or a ghast, making it a much more efficient ghoul-making (or ghast-making) machine, although such creatures *are* free-willed.

   *Pathfinder* took another look at ghouls in [*Classic Horrors Revisted*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ban?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Classic-Horrors-Revisited); I don't know if that contains more information about ghoul-spawning *vis-a-vis* animals.

   In *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *Dungeons and Dragons*--at least *3.5* and earlier--, [ghoul lore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoul_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) sometimes stated that ghouls were cannibals  in life and as punishment (or reward!) became ghouls *spontaneously* in death, giving the DM tacit permission for random ghoul outbreaks. I don't know if such lore remains in *Pathfinder*, but, if so, it makes the spell [*ghoul hunger*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghoul-hunger) much nastier narratively. Lore like this is included in the description of the template dread ghoul.